# generate an event or function callback when a stringproperty is changed via user interface

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties

I have defined a StringProperty as:
`StrParents = StringProperty(default='-1 ',update= GetParent)`, 
and used `prop` to display the property in a panel as: 
`layout.prop(item, 'StrParents', text='parents')`.

I would like now to make some actions (i.e: call a function X()) if the StringProperty was changed from inside the code. And doing another action (i.e:call a function Y()) if the StringProperty was changed from the user via the panel.

How can I achieve such that requirement?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at the context properties, for instance in this example `context.area.type`.  If scene.x is changed in the console it prints `CONSOLE`, a panel in the properties panel `PROPERTIES` etc.  As a test, print the `context.copy()` dictionary to find what suits for your needs.

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import StringProperty

def goober(self, context):
    print(context.area.type)
    return None

bpy.types.Scene.x = StringProperty(update=goober)
```

Comment: Good thinking. Keep in mind that context overriding can be used to simulate a different area (so does temporarily changing the area.type).

Comment: function does not get triggered